# Blazor wasm hosted in blazor server not passing parameters

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor server app hosting a Blazor WASM client. In the _Host.cshtml on the server app, I'm getting a string array and setting it to a property.

```
// .cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ExternalProviders _socialProviders;

    public IndexModel(ExternalProviders socialProviders)
    {
        _socialProviders = socialProviders;
    }

    public string[] ProviderNames { get; set; } = default!;

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        ProviderNames = await _socialProviders.GetProviderNamesAsync();
    }
}

// .cshtml
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <component type="typeof(express_samples_client.App)" 
                       param-CurrentUser="@Model.CurrentUserName"
                       param-SocialProvidersArray="@Model.ProviderNames"
                       render-mode="WebAssembly" />
        </main>
    </div>
```

On the client app.razor, I get that data, and try to set it as a CascadingParameter. I do have the data here.

```
@inject AppClient Client

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue Value="@SocialProvidersArray" Name="SocialProviders">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        ...
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string[] SocialProvidersArray { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>();
```

I've tried to set Cascading Parameters in the client app MainLayout.razor and LogInForm.razor but both have `null` during OnInitialized.

My MainLayout.razor looks like this:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentUser)) // Value not shown in this sample for brevity
{
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="px-4">
        <LogInForm OnLoggedIn="@HandleLogin" SocialProviders="@SocialProviders" />
    </div>
}

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public string[] SocialProviders { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    public string[] SocialProvidersArray { get; set; }
    // Neither of these ^^ get set
```

I also have those CascadingParameters in LogInForm.razor, but they don't get set there either.

Can we set a value in App.razor and get it to child components?